# Retrieving image from Window Azure to Window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I managed to upload an image from Camera Roll to my Window Azure Blob Storage, now I want to retrieve from the storage to Window Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

**To display the image as a part of your app:**

Add an Image element to your XAML somewhere:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="100" Height="125"/>
```

In your code, get a reference to this image

```
public System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = 
     ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("MyImage"));
```

Set the source of the image to the URL of the image in BLOB storage

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));
```

**Alternatively, to download the image and do something with it:**

Use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to download the image.  You'll end up with a stream.  What you do with the stream depends on what you want to do with the image once you've downloaded it.

Comment: Do I need to create a new C# code for this retrieving or add-on to uploading code?

Comment: Without knowing more details about your project and how the downloading of the image relates to the uploading of the image, it's hard to say where the download code should go.

Comment: I followed this: http://buildmobile.com/a-practical-guide-to-photo-sharing-apps-using-windows-phone-and-azure/#fbid=r3j8cw2uWqf